# Why did Sam describe Garth as Ichabod Crane looking?

Tags: supernatural

In Supernatural S09E12 (Sharp teeth) Sam was describing Garth Fitzgerald to the nurse in the hospital saying "He’s a skinny, Ichabod Crane-looking kind of guy."

Why did Sam use that description and the Sleepy Hollow reference? I did watch the movie and TV show Sleepy Hollow, but I still don't see a good connection between a random skinny guy and Ichabod. Am I missing some description from the book?

Comment: Please he was also mentioned by Dean in season 8 ep 22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general description of the character known in the book by Washington Irving. In this excerpt from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Sleepy_Hollow), it says:

> The "Legend" relates the tale of Ichabod Crane, a lean, lanky and extremely superstitious

So, all-in-all, this is just his description. It really has nothing to do with the TV show about Sleepy Hollow or anything of the sort. This is a very well known story in the US, so may not have as much of a following in Croatia and thus your confusion. People can use the descriptor of "Ichabod Crane" here and most people would get the reference.

Comment: Appears I underestimated the popularity of the book,ty.

Comment: I don't know if the book itself, but the story has a lot of notoriety, especially around Halloween.

Answer (score 1):

Try the old school cartoon too.  He was a skinny superstitious guy with a big nose in the disney cartoon.  Don't think Johnny Depp or the new tv series. Think of the old school disney cartoon or actual legend.  :)

Comment: ahahhah he really does look like "Garth" with those big cartoony ears.